# Merging multiple formulas to eliminate help columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Consider this table, in which Col A to C are given strings, and Col D to G are array formulas:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tese |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Afetado | REsp 1872759/SP | 2020/0103921-2 | REsp | Recurso especial | 1872759 | SP |
| 3 | Afetado | REsp 1895255/RS | 2020/0237508-4 | REsp | Recurso especial | 1895255 | RS |
| 4 | Afetado | REsp 1903883/CE | 2020/0288219-1 | REsp | Recurso especial | 1903883 | CE |

Col D formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B<>"", REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,"[^[:space:]]+"),""))
```

Col E formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D<>""; SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2:D, "EREsp", "Embargos em recurso especial"), "AREsp", "Agravo em recurso especial"), "CC", "Conflito de competência"), "REsp", "Recurso especial"), "Pet", "Petição"), "Rcl", "Reclamação"),""))
```

Col F formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B<>"", REGEXREPLACE(B2:B,"\D+", ""),""))
```

Finally, Col G formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B<>"", RIGHT(B2:B;2), ""))
```

All this to help Col H formula return this (note that row in which Col B string is null should return no result):

|  | H |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | Recurso especial 1.872.759/SP (2020/0103921-2) |
| 3 | Recurso especial 1.895.255/RS (2020/0237508-4) |
| 4 | Recurso especial 1.903.883/CE (2020/0288219-1) |

Col H formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E<>""; E2:E&" "&TEXT(F2:F; "#,##0")&"/"&G2:G&" ("&TO_TEXT(C2:C)&")"; ""))
```

Is it possible to build a formula that merges those in Col D to H and achieve the same results?

This is the actual table: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xwTLrz8rFl5U1DL1Y4afWDvjxWSGVh334mcZhz7duH4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell from your example whether you're in a european sheet or not.  If so, change all these commas to semicolons:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",,E2:E&" "&REPLACE(REPLACE(MID(B2:B,6,100),2,0,"."),6,0,".")&" ("&C2:C&")"))
```

Comment: It's a European sheet.

Comment: And what about the SUBSTITUTE part of the formula?

Comment: What about the substitute() part? I don't understand the question?

Comment: There is a lot of substitute() in the formula that I use, but there is none in the one you provide

Comment: Correct. I used a different approach using replace()

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

```
ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:B<>"", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B,"[^[:space:]]+"), "EREsp", "Embargos em recurso especial"), "AREsp", "Agravo em recurso especial"), "CC", "Conflito de competência"), "REsp", "Recurso especial"), "Pet", "Petição"), "Rcl", "Reclamação")&" "&TEXT(REGEXREPLACE(B1:B,"\D+", ""), "#,##0")&"/"&RIGHT(B1:B,2)&" ("&TO_TEXT(C1:V)&")", ""))
```

But, if there is a way to simplify this formula, please share!

Comment: You can simplify formula if you avoid array formula.